# GET-запрос с помощью Retrofit возвращает ошибку, в чём может быть проблема?

Tags: android, веб-сервер, ssl, retrofit

В приложении для Andorid требуется сделать запрос к серверу (получить ответ в формате JSON, обработать его и так далее). Решил попробовать воспользоваться Retrofit, чтобы решить свой вопрос, в примере использовался сайт https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ - и по примеру у меня всё работает. Но стоит изменить ссылку сайта на свою - скрипт возвращает ошибку.

Чтобы попытаться "выловить ошибку" я создал на тестируемом сайте такой же URL-адрес как и в примере, запрос к этому адресу выдает тот же JSON-ответ, что и в примере, единственное различие - это сам домен.
Ставлю свой домен - ошибка, меняю на тот что в примере - всё отлично.

Ранее у меня возникали проблемы с подгрузкой некоторых сайтов в WebView в приложении, сайты с хорошим SSL-сертификатом (google, yandex и другие крупные сайты) - грузятся хорошо, а вот мои сайты, подписанные простыми SSL-сертификатами (доступными физ.лицам) - постоянно выдавали ошибку.

Столкнувшись с проблемой GET-запросов я начал так же грешить на SSL.

Подскажите, действительно ли заключается проблема в сертификате, и как её обойти? И как быть, если у сайта вообще нет SSL?

Пример, который я использовал: https://devcolibri.com/getting-started-with-retrofit-in-android/

Comment: может код покажете какой-то? например как делаете запрос, какую ошибку получаете?

Comment: Я не стал расписывать весь код, так как он есть по ссылке, которую я указал. А вот насчёт ошибки - к сожалению, у меня не получилось найти инструкций, как в Retrofit выловить текст самой ошибки. У меня срабатывает onFailure вместо onResponse, это факт, а вот описание ошибки, увы пока не получил.

Comment: если вы делали все как в примере, то должно все работать, а раз что-то не работает, то покажите код который вы написали. по поводу логгирования запроса - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32514410/logging-with-retrofit-2

Comment: Так оно и работает:) Но как только я использую другой сайт - все ломается. Да, я сейчас попробую включить логгирование и отпишусь позже. Пока что вот ссылка, которую я подставляю вместо примера: https://onlinechkin.com/posts/1 , возможно какие-то заголовки нужны дополнительные в ответе от сервера? Хотя.. не думаю.

Comment: подключите логгирование, и посмотрите через логи что у вас за проблема с этим сайтом)

Comment: Как и предполагалось, ошибка в SSL: HTTP FAILED: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found. И это ужасно:)

Comment: так может нужен токен какой-то? если у сайта нет апи то нужно будет настраивать доступ к нему, или у него есть апи а у вас токен?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, о чём вы. Сайт тут не причём, Андроид просто напросто блокирует запросы к сайтам без SSL или с SSL, которые ему не нравятся, понимаете?

Comment: И я вроде как нашёл на просторах тырнета ответ, как обойти ошибку SSL. Пробую.

Comment: Такие ошибки не обходить надо, а сертификаты правильно настраивать. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html

Answer (score 2):

По результатам SSL labs понятно где проблема.
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=onlinechkin.com

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Промежуточный сертификат отсутствует, поэтому нарушается цепочка доверия.
Мобильные устройства сейчас являются очень недоверчивыми.

Comment: То есть я верно понял, что сайты без SSL сейчас в приложениях вообще никак не получится использовать? По поводу сертификата - есть более точное напутствие по настройке промежуточного сертификата?

Comment: На сервере был установлен только корневой сертификат. Промежуточный, как я понял, нужно указывать в одном поле с корневым, установил, проверил (убрав при этом костыль, обходящий ошибку) - и ошибки уже нет. Видимо, теперь всё правильно настроено? Потестирую ещё, если не возникнет трудностей - отпишусь. Спасибо.

Comment: Все верно, в продакшин без SSL настоятельно не рекомендуется. Только если есть веские основания, и через настройку исключений.

Comment: Сейчас все правильно настроено, если еще отключите на сервере TLS 1.0 и TLS 1.2, будет вообще супер. Но это ограничит круг клиентов на Android 5+.